# TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined in react native sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, react-native

I am trying to run a simple react native code for sqlite storage.
when i run the program i am getting an error Possible Unhandled 
Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined.

Error Screenshot is here:[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5I8E.png)

.Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
SQLite.DEBUG(true);
SQLite.enablePromise(true);
let db ;
export default class ButtonBasics extends Component{
constructor(props)
{super(props);}

componentDidMount()
{
db = SQLite.openDatabase({ name: "sqldb.db", createFromLocation:'~sqldb.db', dblocation: 'Library' },
this.openSuccess, this.openError)
db.transaction(function(tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * from login', [], function(tx, rs) {
console.log('Data Exist): ' + rs);},
function(tx, error)
{
console.log('Data Not Exist ' + error.message);
});
});
}

render()
{
return
(
Some text
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post error screenshot?

Comment: @SanyamJain : okay,i added  a screenshot Link in my post...